# The system cannot find the path specified in cmd

Tags: python, windows-7

When I open my Command Prompt,

the default path is C:\Users\acer>
so I want to change the path to C:\Python27

the method is as follows
i enter cd.. 2 times..
then I enter cd.. Python27 
as my Python27 folder located in C:\

however, I got this message "the system cannot find the path specified"

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `..` is the parent folder - you can either go up two folders, then into the `Python27` folder or go directly as wim says

Answer (score 1):

No need for `cd ..` mumbo jumbo, just go `cd C:/Python27`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

cd.. Python27

you need to type

cd \python27